# Kivy how to show output of a function as text

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am new to Kivy python and I need to develop an mobile APP for android. It is pretty simple in its design but I cant seem to find any way to make it work.

[image]

It seems a very basic design. So, every time the function does a 'print' to the console it should appear on the output. and the function can be ended or started at any time pressing the button.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What part are you asking about? If you have no idea about any of it, break the problem into smaller parts and ask about one of them. For instance, if you don't know how to split the gui into the large output box and small start/end button, ask about that with a code example showing what you've tried.

Comment: It is how to show the output of the function

Comment: It is a continuous function that will run every X time. So to show the output of this function in the 'output' area

Comment: Please give a minimal runnable example showing an example app structure, and a function that you're running, with an output area where you want to show the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
import threading
import time

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
        size_hint_y: .8
        do_scroll_x: False
        Label:
            id: debugarea
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
    Button:
        size_hint_y: .1
        text: 'start'
        on_release:
            app.do_print()
            self.text = 'stop' if app.is_printing else 'start'
'''

class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.is_printing = False
        self.print_thread = None
        self.root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv)

    def build(self):
        return self.root_widget

    def printer(self):
        i = 0
        while self.is_printing:
            self.root_widget.ids['debugarea'].text += f'Hello {i}' + '\n'
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def do_print(self):
        if not self.is_printing:
            self.is_printing = True
            self.print_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.printer)
            self.print_thread.start()
        else:
            self.is_printing = False
            self.print_thread.join()
            self.print_thread = None

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: nice! how do I make it print an outside function?

Comment: IT is almost what I need exactly!

Comment: what do you mean by outside function ? you could modify the printer() function if you want to do something different